# Where do psychologists typically search for literature?

Tags: psychology

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.. If not please advise.

In computer science, we often check digital libraries of ACM, IEEE, etc. And also Google scholar.

But are there search engines that are like **THE** main place to look for psychology literature?

Comment: IANAP, but I use pubmed, google scholar & books, and APA's website "PsychNET", probably in this order.

Comment: N.B.: I don't think the question is that subjective to close; one could look at some meta-analyses and see where they performed their searches. It's usually stated in such papers. The lesser known [APS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_for_Psychological_Science) has [a page on this](http://www.psychologicalscience.org/apssc/uu/articles/literaturesearch.cfm). Looking at that I'm reminded that I sometime search JSTOR directly, particularly for old[er] papers.

Comment: [This book has an advice section](https://books.google.com/books?id=eNsVUGTMcDoC&pg=PA112). By the way, the way you've worded the body of your question kinda reads like "what's the BEST search engine", which is going to be subjective unless someone finds a published survey of psychologists' preferences. Alternatively I can read it as asking for a search engine that ONLY searches psychology publications, which is a bit incongruous with the title. So you might want to clarity what you mean to ask exactly.